# Can't find Microsoft.SQLServer.BatchParserClient.dll. But it's in GAC (maybe)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017

I'm not sure what I've done recently to cause this, but now I cannot run some code that was previously working. I have a C# WPF app running in debug and it's attempting to create a new database in the local SQLExpress instance.  I get an exception that it can't find/load Microsoft.SQLServer.BatchParserClient.dll.  If I go to "C:\Windows\Assembly" it certainly is not there.  However, if I use VS command prompt and execute "gacutil-l," it is listed as being in the GAC.  I've tried re-installing SQLExpress 2016, 2017 and Management Studio.  Nothing has worked.

Comment: are you tring to create the new database from VS or from SSMS ?

Comment: It's in VS... c# code running in debug.

Comment: What code ? I cant see it

Comment: The Microsoft.SqlServer.* assemblies are usually in the SDK folder in the SQL Server program files folder.  However, you might also try looking in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Assembly folder.

Comment: The code isn't the problem, the environment is.  The code is also massive and my company wouldn't appreciate it if I were to post.  It runs in debug just fine on my other machines... just not this current one.

Comment: @BaconBits Ah, yes, you are right.  So I'm still confused at why, all of a sudden, I get an exception.  Both 32 and 64 bit versions are there.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a dependency on the 2008 SMO which had been removed.  Reinstalling the feature pack from SQL 2008 has fixed it.